# ARM THUMB2 function to compare to a number of values

Tags: arm, thumb

I am pretty new to ARM and am looking to compare a value in a register to a selection of known hex values. At the moment I am doing this by using individual CMP instructions so the code looks like this:

```
;stuff

CMP r2, #0x41

CMP r2, #0x45

CMP r2, #0x49

etc...
```

clearly this gets pretty cumbersome after a while and I'm thinking there must a way to compare the value in r2 to a number of hex values all at once.

Aplogies for the newbie question, thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Have the values you want to compare against in an array, and loop over it

Comment: You can do a binary-search-like tree of compares.

Comment: that is kind of the nature of assembly language, they dont have a compare one register to many things at once instruction, certainly not for a RISC, maybe a CISC but I doubt it (saying that might cause someone to show the exception).  you can maybe reduce the number of compares but thumb does not have a compare one to many instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you look at the valid value range.

1. Check the value is in range.
2. Subtract the lowest value from register.
3. Use modified value as array index; array may have a value key or just be a yes/no.

Step 2,3 are only needed if some values in the range are not valid and the array should be fairly densely pack, which for your two digit hex should be the case.

```
  # Range check (step 1)
  cmp r2, #hi_val
  bhi out_of_range
  cmp r2, #low_val         ; optimized version is subs r2, r2, #low_val
  blo out_of_range

  # Adjust value (step 2)
  sub r2, r2, #low_val     ; removed in optimized version.

  # Get check from array (step 3)
  adr r0, key_array
  ldrb r0, [r0, r2]  ; base of array + adjusted value.
  bx   lr            ; return w. result in r0.

# Handle not in range.
out_of_range:
  mov  r0, #-1
  bx   lr            ; use 0xffffffff for out of range.

# This is a constant array included with the code.
key_array:
  .byte 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 # etc.
```

Obviously, your `key_array` must be changed to be valid with your use case.  The condition codes will change slightly for signed and unsigned values.

If `key_array` is all ones for the binary case, then steps two and three are just `return 1;`.  If the `low_val` is zero, then you don't need to subtract (or do a low range check).  The `key_array` should be of size `hi_val - low_val + 1` or your range check logic can change.

This mechanism is used for many 'ctype' functions such as `ispunct`, but you may store up to eight values in a byte and use a bit mask to get the one you are interested in. It is also easy to implement in 'C' and use a compiler. It is possible to use only one register (R0 is EABI compatible function) but then the error handling is also intermixed and less clear.

Comment: I think we could use only `R0` (and be EABI compliant) and also `ldrsb` would benefit this example, but I tried to make this answer accessible.  A value of '255' in the table and `ldrsb` would allow the 'error' checking to be bounds+1 in the array as the error case.  As well as the 'optimized' idea to work with the range corrected index.  But the code becomes more difficult to understand.  Perhaps making a program that could do this for us would be helpful. [tag:compiler-construction].